# Jersey e2e integration tests for in-memory database using Spring's JDBCTemplate

Tags: java, spring, junit, jersey, integration-testing

What is the proper way of designing and running e2e integration tests for Jersey REST API that uses `jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory`, h2 database and `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate`?

**Requirements:**

The test scope should be end-to-end: starting from *resource* and going through all application to the *h2 database*.

**Writing tests:**

Currently my JUnit integration tests fail if run all together from IDE's JUnit, mainly because they interfere with each other(running concurrently with JUnit). Another issue is those should be rolled back after each test, use transaction support ( currently `@Transactional` annotation does nothing to help). What's the minimal set of Spring's tools required to support this kind of tests?
How to make it work? Should `@Transactional` be placed anywhere else?

Example:

```
@Transactional
public class OrderResourceIT extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        // config
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureClient(final ClientConfig config) {
        // config
    }

    @Before
    public void startUp(){
        // database bootstrap programmatically before each test
    }


    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testGetOrders(){
        Response response  = target("/orders")
                .request()
                .get();

        List<Order> orders = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Order>>(){});

        // asserts
    }
}
```

**Execution:**

It's planned to execute with `maven-failsafe-plugin`:

[Failsafe Plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html) suggests binding starting of container to `pre-integration-test phase` and `post-integration-test` at the container termination.
How can it be configured if my `jersey-container-grizzly2-http` container is configured programmatically? [Example](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/griz_jersey_intro/Grizzly-Jersey-Intro.html):

```
public class Main {
    // Base URI the Grizzly HTTP server will listen on
    public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/";

    public static HttpServer startServer() {
        // create a resource config that scans for JAX-RS resources and providers
        // in com.example.rest package
        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.example.rest");

        // create and start a new instance of grizzly http server
        // exposing the Jersey application at BASE_URI
        return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final HttpServer server = startServer();
        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
                + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI));
        System.in.read();
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

Would be perfect to see working example code.

Comment: You cant span the transaction boundary across a HTTP request, so if you need to isolate the tests while they run concurrently then I would spin up a different database/web container per test, similar to how the dropwizard DropwizardAppRule class works, sort of like this: https://gist.github.com/stringy05/76a01aa4d611829ab1b59dd938b9db6d , just need to substitute your spring environment and db layer, should be able to do this with SpringClassRule

Answer (score 1):

I think your scenario is a great fit for dbunit testing. With dbunits, an in-memory database is spawned up for every test case to be executed and is destroyed as the test case execution is complete. The data model of this database entirely depends on the dataset xml you configure. Have a look at this: http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/dbunit_made_easy.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are ample of example provided by jersey as jersey-examples .
There are  set of junit testcases for every module hosting the rest services.

The example can downloaded from jersey download page .
https://jersey.java.net/download.html

Exact links are given below which may change in future.

For all available version:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/jersey-examples

For current latest version:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/jersey-examples/2.23.1/jersey-examples-2.23.1-all.zip

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).